# sed command to copy lines that have strings

Tags: linux, sed, text-processing

I want to copy the line that have strings to another file

for eg

A file contain the below lines

```
ram 100 50
gopal 200 40
ravi 50 40
krishna 300 600
Govind 100 34
```

I want to copy the lines that has 100 or 200 to another file by skipping all the characters before (first occurrence in a line)100 or 200

I want it to copy 
100 50
200 40
100 34
 to another file

I am using sed -n '/100/p' filename > outputfile

can you please help me in adding lines with any one of the string using a single command

Comment: Be careful you don't pick up lines that contain 51003, etc. (i.e. have numbers that contain 100 or 200 rather than ARE 100 or 200). All of the currently posted answers would fail that way. You should update your sample to include those cases and add the expected output. Also, do you want to search for `100` across the whole line or only within 1 or 2 specific space-separated fields on the line? If the latter then edit your example to show those cases you don't want to falsely match too. It's always trivial to find the matches but harder to not select similar lines that shouldn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short ***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/[12]00/!d; s/[^0-9[:space:]]*//g; s/^ *//g;' filename > outputfile
```

- `/[12]00/!d` - exclude/delete all lines that don't match `100` or `200`
- `s/[^0-9[:space:]]*//g` - remove all characters except digits and whitespaces

The `outputfile` contents:

```
100 50
200 40
100 34
```

Comment: actually I have missed to add some details about my requirement. while copying I want to skip all the characters before first occurrence of 100 or 200

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/[12]00/w anotherFile' file
```

Only print if needed, write to `anotherFile` the regexp which matches `100` or `200`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 possibilities:

```
sed -n '/100\|200/p' filename > outputfile

sed -n -e '/100/p' -e '/200/p' filename > outputfile
```

The latter is probably easier to remember and maintain (but maybe you should be using `-f`?), but note that it will print lines twice if they match both. You could fix this by using:

```
sed -n -e '/100/{p;b}' -e '/200/{p;b}' filename > outputfile
```

Then again, why are you using sed? This sounds like a job for `grep`.

Comment: actually I have missed to add some details about my requirement. while copying I want to skip all the characters before first occurrence of 100 or 200

Comment: Note that `s///` has a `p` flag that works very similar to my second answer.